# Ciclos While, solo me muestra información del primero

Tags: php

Tengo varios datos donde debo mostrar esta información, el problema es que me carga solo en el primer ciclo **while** además que deben llevar esta información quedan en blanco.

Consulta a la base de datos

```
<?php
    require ("conexion.php");     
    $getModulos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM modulos") or die ('error al obtener datos de modulos'); 
    ?>
```

Primer Ciclo

```
<select name='modulos' class='editText' id="sel_modulo_b">

 <option selected value='0'> Elige tu modulo </option>
  <?php while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($getModulos)){
  echo "<option value=".$row3['ID'].">".$row3['nombre']."</option>";
  } ?>

</select>
```

Segundo Ciclo

```
<select name='modulos_buscar' class='editText' id="">
       <option selected value='0'> Elige tu modulo </option>
        <?php while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($getModulos))
        {
        echo "<option value=".$row4['ID'].">".$row4['nombre']."</option>";
        } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de no poder hacer otra vez el recorrido es porque dicha función trabaja con un puntero.

Hay dos soluciones para tu problema:

Una usar **[`mysqli_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)**:

```
<?php
require ("conexion.php");     
$getModulos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM modulos") or die ('error al obtener datos de modulos'); 
?>

<!-- Primera consulta -->

<select name='modulos' class='editText' id="sel_modulo_b">
  <option selected value='0'> Elige tu modulo</option>
  <?php while ( $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array( $getModulos ) ) {
    echo "<option value=".$row3[ 'ID' ].">".$row3[ 'nombre' ]."</option>";
  } ?>    
</select>

<!-- Segunda consulta -->

<?php mysqli_data_seek( $getModulos, 0 ); ?>

<select name='modulos_buscar' class='editText' id="">
  <option selected value='0'> Elige tu modulo</option>
  <?php while ( $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array( $getModulos ) ) {
    echo "<option value=".$row4[ 'ID' ].">".$row4[ 'nombre' ]."</option>";
  } ?>
</select>
```

---

**O** almacenar el resultado en un array (este método se usa mayormente):

```
<?php
require ("conexion.php");     
$getModulos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM modulos") or die ('error al obtener datos de modulos'); 
?>

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $getModulos ) ) {
  // Guardar reusltado
  $rows[]  = $row;
}
```

y después iterarlo con un `foreach`:

```
<!-- Primera iteración -->

<select name='modulos' class='editText' id="sel_modulo_b">
    <option selected value='0'> Elige tu modulo</option>

    <?php foreach ( $rows as $v ) {

        echo "<option value=".$v[ 'ID' ].">".$v[ 'nombre' ]."</option>";
    } ?>

</select>

<!-- Segunda iteración -->

<select name='modulos_buscar' class='editText' id="">
    <option selected value='0'> Elige tu modulo</option>

    <?php foreach ( $rows as $v ) {

        echo "<option value=".$v[ 'ID' ].">".$v[ 'nombre' ]."</option>";
    } ?>

</select>
```

Comment: me funciono perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

La función `mysqli_fetch_array` solo la puedes llamar una vez para cada consulta que realices, por eso te está fallando al hacer el segundo ciclo.

Hay varias maneras de solucionarlo, una de ellas hacer la consulta dos veces, aunque no te la recomiendo. Te dejo este ejemplo que creo que es el más correcto para que lo adaptes a tu código.

Haces el `mysqli_fetch_array` y lo guardas dentro de un array.

```
$datos = [];

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta))
    {
        $datos[] = $fila;
    }
```

El array lo puedes recorrer las veces que necesites.

```
foreach ($datos as $fila)
{
        echo "<td>". $fila['COLUMNA_DB'] . "</td>";
}
```